# C# WPF Как сделать созависмую реакцию двух кнопок на триггеры?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть две кнопки. По некоторым причинам их должно быть две, но триггеры у них должны срабатывать будто это одна кнопка. Т.е. при наведении на одну триггер наведения должен срабатывать у обоих. И спадать при отводе тоже у обоих. Как такое сделать в xaml?

Comment: Забабахать свой стиль, который завяжет поведение кнопки на общие свойства, MVVM и привязки данных вам в помощь, вроде легко должно быть.

Comment: На данный момент стиль у этих кнопок один. Я догадываюсь, что их можно как-то забиндить, но какие именно свойства и к чему привязывать додуматься не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал простой пример, без код-бихайнда не получилось, но можете сделать юзерконтрол на основе кнопки.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppSyncButtons.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppSyncButtons"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SyncButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HoverTrigger}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Button1" Style="{StaticResource SyncButtonStyle}" MouseEnter="OnMouseHover" MouseLeave="OnMouseHover"/>
            <Button Content="Button2" Style="{StaticResource SyncButtonStyle}" MouseEnter="OnMouseHover" MouseLeave="OnMouseHover"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool hoverTrigger;

    public bool HoverTrigger
    {
        get => hoverTrigger;
        set
        {
            hoverTrigger = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OnMouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HoverTrigger = sender is Button button && button.IsMouseOver;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Обе зеленеют при наведении на одну из них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. А какова идея с собственным контролом? Создать какое-то статическое свойство, которое будет отвечать за Наведение и как-то плясать от него?

Comment: @Николайн нет, упаковать в юзерконтрол этот же самый код. Забудьте про статику, она не для этого существует.

Comment: @Николайн если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: я так и сделал, но не имею репутации и счетчик не повышается

Comment: @Николайн голосование и отметка ответа как решения - две разные функции